# UIScrollView Button Paging

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, uistoryboard

I've been trying to make a 100x100 pixel scroll view (paging mode) that displays a single button at 75x75 per page. I can get the first image to appear but I'm not able to page to the next. Here's the code I've been using, can somebody please help me out?

.h

```
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollMenu;
```

.m

```
@synthesize scrollMenu;

-(void)viewDidLoad {

scrollMenu.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfButtons = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {

    //Array of images for the buttons
    NSArray *menuItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], nil];

    //Create A Button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    //Give the button an action
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(menuItemSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //Give the button an image
    [button setImage:[menuItems objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Most likely WRONG
    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(20+75), 8.0, 75, 75);


    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    //Assign a tag
    button.tag = i;

    //Add the button to the view
    [scrollMenu addSubview:button];

}
//Most likely WRONG
scrollMenu.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100,100);
[self.view addSubview:scrollMenu];
 }

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar kind of thing but for UIImageView. Here you just need to set some properties of UI ScrollView and need to implement one delegate method.

First set some of properties

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    _scrollView.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    _scrollView.directionalLockEnabled=YES;
    _scrollView.canCancelContentTouches=YES;
    _scrollView.delaysContentTouches=YES;
    _scrollView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    _scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal=YES;
    _scrollView.bounces=YES;
    _scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    _scrollView.delegate=self;

}
```

Implement delegate method

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    @try
    {
        CGFloat pageWidth = 320;    //scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

        if (page >9)
            page = page - 3;
        if (page <[listOfPictures count])
        {
            [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320*page, _scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
            currentPicIndex = page;
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        TRACE_ERROR(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating", exception.name, exception.description);
    }

}
```

My scrollview of is 240X300. So please manipulate with pixels of button, scrollview and set ContentOffSet like wise.

Hoping this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for.